# Java generic method declaration

Tags: java, generics

I'm learning Java generics and I ask myself this question.

What is the difference between these two method declarations?

```
public static void someMethod(List<? extends Number> numberList);
```

and

```
public static <E extends Number> void someMethod(List<E> numberList);
```

Comment: using the second one allows you to reference E in your `someMethod`s code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the latter you have a reference to the type within the scope of `someMethod`, namely `E`. In the former you do not.

Answer (score 14):

The main difference is that the latter is a **generic method** the former is not.

So for example in the latter method you can do something like this:

```
public static <E extends MyObject> void someMethod(List<E> someList) {
    E myObject = someList.iterator().next(); // this can actually lead to errors
    myObject.doSomething();                  // so treat it as an example
}
```

This means that you can substitute an arbitrary type `E` which conforms to the rule in the generic method declaration and be able to use that type in your method.

Be advised though that you should call the generic method with type arguments like this:

```
someClass.<MyArbitraryType>someMethod(someList);
```

You can find a nice overview of generic methods [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: In java Se 7 and above you can call this `someClass.somemethod(someList);` i belive, don't have se7 compiler atm, please confirm?

Comment: I don't have se7 compiler atm either.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But why would I want E? With the former version I can do
`for(Number numb: numberList) {
numb.anyMethodOfNumber();
}`

Isn't it the same?

Answer (score 5):

With the second version you can do something like:

```
public static <E extends Number> void someMethod(List<E> numberList) {
  E number = numberList.get(0); 
  numberList.add(number);
}
```

This isn't possible with the first version.

Answer (score 2):

Using the first method declaration will not allow you to add anything new to the list. For example this will not compile.

```
public static void someMethod(List<? extends Number> numberList, Number number) {
    numberList.add(number);
}
```

while the second allows you to do this:

```
public static <T extends Number> void someMethod(List<T> numberList, T number) {
    numberList.add(number);
}
```

Comment: Using the second wont either.

Comment: You can add elements to the list, as long as the element to be added is of type E or a subclass.

Comment: I'm using java SE 6 and its not possible.

Comment: are you sure we're talking about the same thing? `<T extends Number> void method(List<T> list, T number) {list.add(number);}` should compile just fine.

Comment: mine doesn't compile, I have to cast number. numbers.add((E)number1); is fine

Comment: Btw number isnt type T, its type Number, as stated in the answer. Please look above

Comment: @ZeDonDino ofcourse you cannot add a number to a `List<T extends Number>` because of up-casting.  i never said this is possible.

Comment: By my analogy logic I thought, that you thought this. : ) Sorry mate, didn't want to insult you